# Change language name based on the domain i'm on

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm looking for a solution which can alter/change a language name based on the domain I'm on.

Here I can configure one name, which is used everywhere, but can't be configured for each domain:
/admin/config/regional/language

I got a site with multiple domains. Every domain has a set of languages: en, nl and fr etc.

Each domain has different labels for those languages. For example:
domain 1: en: English
domain 2: en: International

Any suggestions?

Altering every form, every view output, just feels wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for url/domain language negociation + url/path language negociation, right ?
You need both of domain+path in */admin/config/regional/language/detection/url* to determine wich language to display.

I think you have to implement a new LanguageNegociation plugin in a module which do this. Have a look at :

**core/modules/language/src/Plugin/LanguageNegotiation/LanguageNegotiationUrl.php**

You should be able to get your own detector (quiet looking like LanguageNegotiationUrl with both domain+path) by extending LanguageNegotiationMethodBase.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Enable language negotiation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/enable-language-negotiation) page in the [Multilingual guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual).  It's explained in there.

> Generally, the URL method will be enabled and will be the first on the
>   list, meaning that if the language is specified in the URL of the
>   page, the page will be displayed in that language. The URL method can
>   be configured to use either the domain or language path prefix of the
>   page. If the language is not specified in the URL, the next method on
>   the list will be used.